# RabbitMQ - Multiple instances reading from the same Topic

Tags: python, apache-kafka, rabbitmq

I have multiple producers from different applications sending messages to topics in RabbitMQ. And multiple consumers from different applications reading those topics. This simple architecture have been working perfectly as a PoC.
But now I have multiple instances from those applications and I don't want app X instance 1 reading the same message as app X instance 2. However app X and app Y (with all their instances) need to red from the same topic.

I know Karaf balances the consumption of Messages from topics if the consumers share the same consumer ID. This feature exists in RabbitMQ? I've been reading the docs and I don't find nothing like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you need kafka's consumer group feature.

(For every message, different consumer groups should consume it together, but just one consumer in every consumer group can consume this message)

See [rabbitmq getstarted](http://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html), you can combine `Topics` mode & `Work queues` mode to realize this feature.

***Sample code***

***receive.py***

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pika
import sys

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(
    host='localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()

channel.exchange_declare(exchange='topic_logs',
                         type='topic')

queue_name = sys.argv[1]
channel.queue_declare(queue=queue_name)

channel.queue_bind(exchange='topic_logs',
                   queue=queue_name,
                   routing_key='my_key')

print ' [*] Waiting for logs. To exit press CTRL+C'

def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    print " [x] %r:%r" % (method.routing_key, body,)
    ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag = method.delivery_tag)

channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)
channel.basic_consume(callback,
                      queue=queue_name)

channel.start_consuming()
```

***send.py***

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pika
import sys

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(
    host='localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()

channel.exchange_declare(exchange='topic_logs',
                         type='topic')

routing_key = 'my_key'
message = 'Hello World!'
channel.basic_publish(exchange='topic_logs',
                      routing_key=routing_key,
                      body=message)
print " [x] Sent %r:%r" % (routing_key, message)
connection.close()
```

***How to run it?***

You need to start 4 consumers to explain this question:

```
python receive.py consumer_group1
python receive.py consumer_group1
python receive.py consumer_group2
python receive.py consumer_group2
```

Above crossponding to app1(instance1), app1(instance2), app2(instance1), app2(instance2)

Then, start send.py:

```
python send.py
```

You will see just one instance of every app that can get the message.
If you send it again, another instance from two different apps can receive the message.